# Included library not found at build

Tags: c++, platformio

I have the following files:

```
main.cpp
lib/EEPROMManager/EEPROMManager.cpp
lib/EEPROMManager/EEPROMManager.h
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <EEPROMManager.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
```

EEPROMManager.h:

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
```

EEPROMManager.cpp:

```
#include <EEPROMManager.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
```

When I build:

```
lib/EEPROMManager/EEPROMManager.h:2:20: fatal error: EEPROM.h: No such file or directory
```

If I include EEPROM.h only in EEPROMManager.cpp, the code builds without any problem. As soon as it's included in EEPROMManager.h, the build fails.
If I include it only in EEPROMManager.h, the build fails.

There's obviously something I don't understand about how dependency work, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT:**

EEPROM.h is part of the Arduino Framework in Platformio. It is located:

```
.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/EEPROM/src
```

I checked c_cpp_properties.json, the above path is included.
Including the full path instead of EEPROM.h fixes the issue. This seems to be a PlatformIO configuration issue, but I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: What is `<EEPROM.h>`? Where is it located?

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to look for includes.